Chat GPT like implementation for organizational data in Google Cloud
I have a requirement where, I am looking for service in Google to process my Organization documents and respond to queries customers ask for from the organization documents only.
Regarding the security constraints, my documents should be dwelled in Google cloud storage and responses for the queries should be extracted from my organization documents only. It should not retrieve information from internet.
I have seen such feature in Azure AI. I am looking for similar feature in Google.
I did research on this in internet. But I did not get relevant solution.
Can someone please let me know if such feature exist in Google cloud.
Regards
Harish Alwala

Hi @Harish Alwala, could you elaborate more on your requirements, and also provide the documentation of azure that fulfills the requirement ?

Sure, In Azure AI, there is a feature to upload our documents, index it and deploy the model and index will be linked to it. This way When I run the GPT like APIs using prompts, I get response from my documents only.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-mechanics-blog/can-chatgpt-work-with-your-enterprise-data/ba-p/3789378

Cloud you try using vertex AI custom models for your requirement ? Let me know if this is helpful or not.
